# DataTable linq query to group by a column

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have developed a Windows application using C#. Used a DataTable to list all information. That Data-Table has duplicate values.

My result:

```
Lead Owners             <2Days  <5Days  <10Days <20Days >20Days Grand-Total
Dan Mahoney                                1                
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Wayne Dunne              1              
Wayne Dunne              1              
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Wayne Dunne              1              
Richard James Whitaker            1             
Richard James Whitaker            1
```

Expected Result:

```
Lead Owners             <2Days  <5Days  <10Days <20Days >20Days Grand-Total
Dan Mahoney                                1                
Richard James Whitaker            7             
Wayne Dunne              3
```

I need a linq query to achieve the expected result.

Kindly help me to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the expected result also a `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new `DataTable` that contains the aggregated values LINQ is not the best tool for the whole task. You should use `DataTable.Clone` to create an empty table with the same schema.

Then use can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` on your source table's key-column. Finally use a loop to add the `DataRow`s with the aggregated values:

```
var ownerGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Lead Owners"));
var dt2 = dt.Clone();
var intColumns = dt2.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(int)).ToArray();
foreach (var grp in ownerGroups)
{
    var row = dt2.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField("Lead Owners", grp.Key);
    foreach (DataColumn col in intColumns)
    {
        bool anyNonNull = grp.Any(r => r.Field<int?>(col.Ordinal).HasValue);
        int? sum = anyNonNull ? grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int?>(col.Ordinal)) : null;
        row.SetField(col, sum);
    }
}
```

I have presumed that the type of the numeric columns is `int`.

Resulting table:

```
Dan Mahoney                 null        null       1
Richard James Whitaker      null        7          null 
Wayne Dunne                 3           null       null
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. This is my expectation. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
from r in table.AsEnumerable()
group r by r.Field<string>("Lead Owners") into g
select new {
   LeadOwners = g.Key,
   2Days = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int?>("2Days")),
   5Days = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int?>("5Days"))
   // etc
}
```

You can use CopyToDataTable method to create new DataTable from query results, if you really need it to be DataTable: [Creating a DataTable From a Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx)