# Group By from DataTable using linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Hi all I am having a result set as follows

```
    ID      Name     Price
     1      XYZ       10
     2      ABC       10
     1      ABC       20
```

I would like to perform group by so that it should give me

```
    ID      Name     Price
     1      XYZ       10
            ABC       20
     2      ABC       10
```

I tried with the solution form the links but I couldn't get [DataTable linq query to group by a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834954/datatable-linq-query-to-group-by-a-column) can some one help me

Comment: Your expected output is not grouped, it is simply ordered by id then price and for some reason on the second record you are not displaying the id.

Comment: But I don't want to display the ID once there

Comment: I am binding the data to a listview so it is displaying me multiple but I would like to show as per posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to change the original objects, you're going to have to project to a *new* collection and remove the repeated ID values.  Something like:

```
var query = 
    data.GroupBy(d => d.ID)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .SelectMany(g => (new[] {new {
                                      g.First().ID, 
                                      g.First().Name, 
                                      g.First().Price}})
                         .Concat(g.Skip(1).Select(i => new {
                                                            ID = (string)null, 
                                                            i.Name, 
                                                            i.Price})));
```

essentially:

- Group by ID
- Take all values of the first item in each group
- Take all values except Id for all other items in the group

Comment: How can I frame this from Datatable?

Comment: Same principle, just use column access instead of property access (`i["ID"]` instead of `i.ID`)

Comment: One help my `int` is `string` so how can I work it out

Comment: I updated the answer.  The only reason to convert to `int?` was to allow for a null (blank) value.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something as simple as this

```
context.Table.GroupBy(t => t.ID);
```

This will return something of this type `IQueryable<IGrouping<int, YourClass>>` (assuming your ID is an int)

Each entry will have a Key (the ID in this case) and an Enumerator so you can go through all the records grouped